# Firebase: Tracking App_remove from campaign with Google Tag Manager

Tags: android, firebase, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

we have in our App Firebase and the Google Tag Manager integrated. And we are new with App GTM and Firebase (so we are in the learning phase).

So we have a campaign with a 3rd Party Company (they are supported in Firebase) and track already the first_open from then.

Now we want also track the app_remove within the Tag Manager (so we dont need the development)

Based on my experience with the Web-GTM I created a trigger where i said:
Trigger type: Campaign
This trigger fires on: Campaign Source equals {campaign_name} AND Event Name equals app_remove

Then I created a Tag with the type "Google Analytics (firebase)" and defined it to add a event and give them a event a name then i added the trigger.

But after the publish (a few days later) the event is not there or any sign it has worked.

Any ideas what I´ve done wrong?

Thanks!